# Get AWS credentials for CLI from federated role

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have access to an AWS console through One Login, in which I'm assigned a role to do my business.  I want to set up the CLI tool but since I don't have my own user credentials, I'm a little unclear on how to generate the access and secret access key.  I don't have the ability to create a user, although that would definitely be a dumb way to go even if I could.  All my Googling says to look it up from the user page or use AWS SSO, neither of which are an option for me

Comment: Onelogin provides a tool https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/samples/aws-cli

Answer (score 1):

You can generate temporary credentials. But this is not possible if you already use temporary credentials afaik.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_use-resources.html#using-temp-creds-sdk-cli

Best case would be:
Ask your SysOps or DevOps engineer to provide you CLI credentials.

Comment: I believe their real question was how to use awscli with onelogin saml idp.

Comment: Good to know that this exists. I thought this is the same as using a role to login.

Comment: It is similar. The end result will look the same as an assumed role, just the way of assuming it is different due to going through a federated 3rd party.

Comment: Cool--I suspected it was something I needed someone else to give me permission for but I'm a new hire and wanted to make sure I had exhausted my options first